# Converting Celsius to Kelvin

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a big list of Gibbs vs T data. Temperatures have to be converted to kelvin.

```
List={{50.011, -40.177}, {50.997, -39.709}, {51.993, -39.881}, {52.999,-39.813}}
```

How can I add 273.15 to the first number of each sublist in List?

Comment: You can't use `List` as a variable name since it's a built-in symbol. If the variable name were `list`, the solution would be `# + {273.15, 0} & /@ list`.

Comment: The solution in C.E.'s comment works well in this case.  Note, however, that `{#1 + 273.15, ##2} & @@@ list` or even `MapAt[ # + 273.15 &, 1 ] /@ list` might generalize better to different situations.

Comment: `MapAt[ QuantityMagnitude@ UnitConvert[Quantity[#, "Celsius"], "Kelvin"]&,list, {All, 1}]`   :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some possible solutions

```
{#[[1]] + 273.15, #[[2]]} & /@ list

MapAt[# + 273.15 &, list, {All, 1}]

Transpose@{list[[All, 1]] + 273.15, list[[All, 2]]}

list + ConstantArray[{273.15, 0}, Length@list]
```